# one of my methods has completely different execution time for same input

Tags: c#

i have a web service which should return an answer in less than 10 milliseconds. i have to many validation process including mobile number validation. every thing works fine but my mobile number validation execution time is completely different!! sometimes it returns in less than a millisecond and sometimes its about 2 seconds!! please take a look at to part of my log file:(same entry in different times)

```
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 9:51:09,073];[11];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[1800.2534 ms]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 10:47:53,636];[5];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[5.4598 ms]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 10:51:09,073];[38];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.1379 ms]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 11:12:09,073];[45];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[1780.4578 ms]
```

and here is my method:

```
public bool MobileContentValidator()
{
    Regex len = new Regex(@"^.{2,20}$"); //length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20
    Regex number = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*$"); //a string consisting only of numbers

    PhoneNumber mobile;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    sw.Start();

    try
    {
        if (!len.IsMatch(this.Number))
        {
            this.IsNumberValid = false;
            this.UserReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "MC0001");
            this.LogReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("log", "MC0001");
        }
        else if (!number.IsMatch(this.Number))
        {
            this.IsNumberValid = false;
            this.UserReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "MC0001");
            this.LogReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("log", "MC0001");
        }
        else if (this.Region != "IR")
        {
            this.IsNumberValid = false;
            this.UserReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "MB0003");
            this.LogReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "MB0003");
        }
        else
        {
            mobile = phoneUtil.Parse(this.Number, this.Region);
            if (phoneUtil.IsValidNumber(mobile) != true)
            {
                this.IsNumberValid = false;
                this.UserReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "MC0001");
                this.LogReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("log", "MC0001");
            }
            else if (phoneUtil.GetNumberType(mobile).ToString() != "MOBILE")
            {
                this.IsNumberValid = false;
                this.UserReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "MU0001");
                this.LogReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("log", "MU0001");
            }
            else
                this.IsNumberValid = true;
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Tools_Log.GetLogger().Info(Tools_Log.MessageForLogFile("mobile content validation completed successfully. ", "", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.UserReason = Tools_MessageAccess.GetBriefMessage("user", "G00001");
        this.LogReason = ex.ToString();
        Tools_Log.GetLogger().Error(Tools_Log.MessageForLogFile("mobile content validation failed due to the exception in application. ", ex.ToString(), sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
        return false;
    }
}
```

i know googles `libphonenumber` library is little heavy but i don't know why sometimes it took so long to returns a answer. as i said i have many validation process and just this one act strange. 
Thanks.

**Update#1:**
i thought the question is clear. my bad. sorry about that.
the question is why execution time is completely different and how can i fix it? i mean did i make a mistake in writing method?

**Update#2:**
more logs:

```
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:33,793];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.ConvertNumber];[0.3712];[];[(Message: converting mobile number completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:33,794];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[2100.12];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:33,797];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.0761];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:33,797];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.ConvertNumber];[0.3456];[];[(Message: converting mobile number completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:37,395];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.ConvertNumber];[0.3452];[];[(Message: converting mobile number completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:37,395];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.0496];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:37,398];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.0752];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:37,399];[14];[Intermediate_Mobile.ConvertNumber];[0.3593];[];[(Message: converting mobile number completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:38,518];[11];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.0768];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:38,518];[11];[Intermediate_Mobile.ConvertNumber];[0.3776];[];[(Message: converting mobile number completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:38,518];[11];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.0492];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:38,521];[11];[Intermediate_Mobile.MobileContentValidator];[0.0966];[];[(Message: mobile content validation completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
[INFO ];[2015-08-25 12:03:38,521];[11];[Intermediate_Mobile.ConvertNumber];[0.383];[];[(Message: converting mobile number completed successfully. )(Exeption: )]
```

Comment: and the question is? ... (well the answer might be profiling ... I think)

Comment: Is this consistent? Are there "slow" numbers and "fast" numbers? Please show examples of both.

Comment: I'd use `this.Number.Length >= 2 && ...` instead of a RegEx for a length check

Comment: dear @DrKoch. i didn't understand your question. would you please explain what you want? i tested the method with this number: 9129856568. and also this method is part of the non-static mobile class.

Comment: i don't think its because of regex!

Comment: You say the routine sometimes takes very long. Does it depend on the input? i.e. are there strings which **always** take a long time and others which **always** run fast?

Comment: no. no. please read the title: one of my methods has completely different execution time for same input. thanks.

Comment: Add more log output with timing info. I'd guess it is something in `PhoneNumberUtil`

Comment: When you say webservice is the time of execution including the latency of the http call?

Comment: What does `GetBriefMessage` do?

Comment: dear @AlexKeySmith: if you take a look at the log output you will see the execution time is just for the content validator method. not the web service output.

Comment: dear @odyss-jii its just a simple method read from a dictionary. it take less than 0.0001 millisecond. here the log for this method: [DEBUG];[2015-08-25 12:26:17,559];[11];[Main_DataBase.GetErrorBriefDescription.ud_prc_getErrorBriefDescription];[0.0004]

Comment: Are you calling the methods during the same runtime or different runtimes?

Comment: Thanks @Dan I wasn't sure if the log was for the client or server.

Comment: dear @AlexKeySmith. you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated log shows that there is a 2 second load time just once. This is (kind of) normal if you use a (larger) external library, which probably needs to load some assemblies when called the first time. You should not see such a delay in the following calls with same input (and hence same control flow through the library)

Comment: at first i thought its just it. but unfortunately it happens a lot. not only at first time.

Answer (score 1):

Though the exact solution to your problem is not clear to me, but you can improve the performance by compiling the RegEx once and use it always and keep it static. Then use that static compiled RegEx object. For more details look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thank you. but mobile validation is a complex process and also its not just about string validation. i know its difficult to find out the exact solution but i hope at least someone suggest the alternative solution.